# AWS VPN issue routing to 2nd ip block

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I've just setup a VPN link between our local network and an Amazon VPC.

Our local network has two ip blocks of interest:

- 192.168.0.0/16 - block local-A
- 10.1.1.0/24 - block local-B

The AWS VPC has a ip block of:

- 172.31.0.0/16 - block AWS-A

I have setup the VPN connection with static routes to the local-A and local-B ip blocks.

I can connect from:

- local-A to AWS-A and
- AWS-A to local-A.

I can't connect from:

- AWS-A to local-B (e.g. 173.31.17.135 to 10.1.1.251)

From the 173.31.17.135 server, 10.1.1.251 seems to be resolving to an Amazon server, rather than a server on our local network. This is despite setting up local-B (10.1.1.0/24) as a route on the VPN. See tracert output...

```
tracert 10.1.1.251

Tracing route to ip-10-1-1-251.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal [10.1.1.251]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  169.254.247.13
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  169.254.247.21
  3    33 ms    35 ms    36 ms  169.254.247.22
  4    34 ms    35 ms    33 ms  ip-10-1-1-251.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal [10.1.1.251]
```

How can I change the config so that the 10.1.1.251 address resolves to the server on my local network when accessed from within AWS?

Disclosure - I've asked this at [stackoverflow too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203436/aws-vpn-issue-routing-to-2nd-ip-block)

Comment: Sounds like you didn't add a to-local-B rule in the VPC routing table.